# Is there any way to force async NSURLConnection to call connectionDidFinishLoading in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I download images in the background that I show inside a `UITableView` cell.

images are not shown until UITableView stops scrolling.

I want to show the downloaded image in a quicker way. For example, I would like to do this while UITableView begins decelerating.

To do this, I need to know when the download is finished and I can't know it until connectionDidFinishLoading is called. This method is not called while UITableView is moving. (or probably while the interface is busy)

Is it possible to somehow make it call connectionDidFinishLoading while UI is busy, **without** synchronously using NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do:

- Have your net connection update objects in Core Data.
- Setup an NSFetchedResultsController somewhere around your UITableView or Controller to query for objects of that type, e.g. `images` collection on an `article` object.
- Bind the UiTableView datasource to the NSFetchedResultsController - i.e. sections and rows of the table come from the results.

At this point, the table view should successfully show any old/current items as you scroll. Now, ...

- When your download completes (maybe an image associated with the e.g. article), update the object in CoreData somehow -- for e.g. simply inserting `image` into a collection on `articles` called `images` -- something that the results controller will "see" based on the initial predicate you setup. If the indexPath of the new object (article, image, whatever) is currently viewable in the tableView, the tableView and results controller will hash it out for you.

You should actually be done at this point, and the new images may just show up. The results controller is KVO observing for you. You *do* need to take action with the results controller gets changes, but there are plenty of examples out there, like [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/01/navigation-based-core-data-application.html) (and there's much much variance between the approaches). If not, you likely need to do something innocuous - e.g. for a scroll to top when new articles appear; avoid calling `reloadData` unless you absolutely have to.

**Update**

If you are just trying to enforce NSURLConnection to operate synchronously or asynchronously, then all you have to do is setup the NSURLConnection using `+ (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate` (or the related initializers) and `- (void)start` instead of `+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error`. The first method loads data asynchronously, while the latter is synchronous.

However, since you mention `connectionDidFinishLoading`, it seems you are setting up the connection asynchronously, no?

Comment: thank you for the walkthrough, however, this still does not directly or indirectly help me on the question: Isn't there a way instead of using NSURLConnection synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to make a synchronous NSURLConnection run in the background is using GCD.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
                   {

```
                  // Do your synchronous NSURLConnection and handle the response


                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                          // update UI  

                        });
                 });
```

You can also use SDWebImage that handles image loading nicely.
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage